# NotSupportedException get_HasShutdownStarted - "This icall is not supported by il2cpp

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm getting the following exception from my iOS App (Which was build with Unity3d):

```
NotSupportedException: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/External/il2cpp/il2cpp/libil2cpp/icalls/mscorlib/System/Environment.cpp(166) : Unsupported internal call for IL2CPP:Environment::get_HasShutdownStarted - "This icall is not supported by il2cpp
```

This is the C# stackstrace that I have:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueueThreadLocals.Finalize () (at <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0)
System.UnhandledExceptionEventHandler:Invoke(Object, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
```

Anything I can do?

Comment: What Unity version are you using?

Comment: The latest: 2017.1.1f1

Comment: You should probably submit a bug report since this might be a problem with Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Unity. We have corrected it, and the fix should be available in the 2017.1.1p3 patch release of Unity.

Answer (score 0):

this bug is still present in 2017.2.0p3.

NotSupportedException: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/External/il2cpp/il2cpp/libil2cpp/icalls/mscorlib/System/Environment.cpp(166) : Unsupported internal call for IL2CPP:Environment::get_HasShutdownStarted - "This icall is not supported by il2cpp

Comment: I think the fix slipped back a patch release, unfortunately.